# c++ returning const reverse iterator from a class method, but method cannot be const?

Tags: c++, methods, iterator, constants, const-iterator

I am trying to return a const reverse iterator from a class method. But my code doesn't compile when I mark my method as `const`. Without `const` the code compiles with no troubles.

Any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class ValueType>
class DynamicDataComponent {
    using ValuesType = std::vector<ValueType>;
    using IteratorType = typename std::vector<ValueType>::reverse_iterator;

public:
    DynamicDataComponent()
    {
        values.push_back(0);
        values.push_back(1);
        values.push_back(2);
        values.push_back(3);
    }

    const IteratorType getRBeginIt() const {
        return values.rbegin();
    }

private:
    ValuesType values;
};

int main() {
    DynamicDataComponent<size_t> dataComponent;
    std::cout << *dataComponent.getRBeginIt() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: and please include the error message. If you dont understand it no problem, others can explain it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a *const-iterator* too:

```cpp
using ConstIteratorType = std::vector<ValueType>::const_reverse_iterator;
```

And define your `const` qualified member function like so:

```cpp
ConstIteratorType getRBeginIt() const {
    return values.rbegin(); // or even `return values.crbegin()` to be clear
}
```

---

Note that a *const-iterator* is not a `const iterator`. The `ConstIteratorType` instance returned by `getRBeginIt() const` isn't `const` (or else you wouldn't be able to iterate with it), but when you dereference the iterator, it'll return a `const ValueType&` or `const ValueType*`.

Comment: I would argue that top-level const in return value is pretty useless.

Comment: its not just useless but prevents certain optimizations afaik

Comment: Copy-paste error :-) Amended

Comment: Early Congrats on your 100K Ted! Well done!

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Oh :) Thanks!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai can you explain this further?

Comment: @MiroslavKrajcir I dont actually remember ..., before move semantics was a thing, it was even a valid recommendation to make return types `const`. With move semantics it prevents to move from the returned value, not sure if theres anything else